# Load Custom SQL query into array in Studio 3T

Tags: mongodb, studio3t

I have a table called SOURCE_CATEGORY and would like to use Studio 3T to load the data from MSSQL to MongoDB.

[image]

I wrote a custom SQL to group the NAME column to combine as String, but in Studio 3T, how can I make the NAME column into array(based on the SOURCEID field) to insert into MongoDB?
[image]

If Studio 3T cannot manage it, can I use MongoDB to split the column's value into array? split by comma for each record/document in Mongodb?